# New Remote Desktop and 2003 Server

Tags: windows-server-2008

Is it possible to use the new Windows 2008 remote desktop client server functionality which lets you copy/paste to the machine with a Windows 2003 server?  I take it there has been an update to terminal servives to allow this functionality in 2008 and wondered if there was an update we could do.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I've always been able to copy and paste in 2003 and XP. It's called clipboard redirection. Perhaps yours has been disabled? (it even works with the linux RDP clients, sometimes)

From: [Technet: Configuring Remote Desktop](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457106.aspx)

**Disabling Clipboard Redirection**

For enhanced security, you might choose to disable Remote Desktop clipboard redirection for clients that connect via the Remote Desktop Web Connection client. You can disable clipboard redirection by using the Do not allow clipboard redirection Terminal Services Group Policy.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste hase been availible in Terminal Services/RDP since Windows 2000 Server. You may want to check this has not been disabled on your terminal server, open up tscc.msc on your server, then go to RDP-Tcp Properties => Client Settings and check that is availble.

I have seen some reports that user have need to allow drive mappings on the RDP connection for it to work, although i've had it working fine without.